# Audio-Video Sync Issue in Windows 7 Media Center

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-center, avi

During playback of AVI file in WMC 7 there is a delay of about .5 sec in audio compared to video. Does anyone know of a way to tweak (maybe reg hack), the audio play back, like you can in vlc and other media players, to compensate for the delay?

Answer (score 2):

[Tutorialsroom](http://www.tutorialsroom.com/tutorials/av/vdub_adjust_sync.html) suggests [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/):

> - Open your video file in VirtualDub by dragging and dropping the file on
>     the program.
> - Click on Audio -> Interleaving or press (Ctrl + I) on your keyboard.
> - Now in Audio skew correction text box type a value in millisecond (1000
>     ms = 1 second) following the
>     instructions: Use positive values if
>     audio is playing too early or negative
>     values if the opposite is true.
>
>   [image]
> - Click Ok and don't forget to Click Video -> Direct stream copy and Audio
>     -> Direct stream copy because we do not want re-encoding here.
> - Click File -> Save as AVI or press F7 on your keyboard and save the file.

Comment: Thanx for the answer! I'm more interested in adjusting the delay during dynamic playback, since when I play the file in vlc for e.g. the audio IS in sync, it's just the media player in msft that introduces the delay. So if I could just tweak the audio in msft player that would be awesome!

Comment: Let me see what I can find, though I think it's going to be difficult to find :(